# How to calculate Two's (2's) Complement in Python

Tags: python

I am writing my own **Servo Driver Program** in Python and I struggle quite a bit with **Two's (2's) Complement** calculation.

Example: I want to have "**-100**" as an input and get "**FF9C**" or just "**9C**" which would also work for the output.

The following picture might help to clarify:

[image: 2's calculation I want in python]

Comment: `hex(-100 & 0xffff) == '0xff9c'` and `hex(-100 & 0xff) == '0x9c'`. This of course works with other negative numbers, too.

Comment: `n = -100 ; print(f'hex "{n:x}" ; two complement: "{n&(2**16-1):x}"')` -> `hex "-64" ; two complement: "ff9c"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much for the help. I ended up using this for my code for other people having the same difficulty.

```
n = -100
x = f'{n&(2**16-1):x}'
print(x) # -> ff9c
```